# How to get the nested field value in python

Tags: python

```
"metadata": {
"kind": "compute#metadata",
"items": [
{
"key": "serial-port-logging-enable",
"value": "true"
},
{
"key": "cluster-name",
"value": "cluster-1"
},
```

I want to print the value of `value`, when the `key` is `"cluster-name"`

So here I want to print `cluster-1` from the above data.

Can someone help me with what I can do?

---

My try

```
cluster_name = (response['metadata']['items'][0]('key'))
```

Comment: What was the problem? Do you know how to access values in lists given an index? Do you know how to access values in dictionaries given a key? Is this a string? Did you already parse it as JSON (it looks like it is JSON)?

Comment: Yes i want to know how to access the nested value here. Also, I only want the nester value for a given key

Comment: @kunal Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: This is what i tried but I am not getting the output I need for my requirement cluster_name = (response['metadata']['items'][0]('key'))

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the position, you need to iterate to fine the valid item

```
response = {
    "metadata": {
        "kind": "compute#metadata",
        "items": [
            {"key": "serial-port-logging-enable", "value": "true"},
            {"key": "cluster-name", "value": "cluster-1"}]
    }}

for item in response['metadata'].get('items', []):
    if item["key"] == "cluster-name":
        print(item['value'])
        break
else:
    print(None)
```

edit :

- added `.get('items', [])` in case the key doesn't exist
- added `break/else` to print None, in case there is no match

Comment: I am getting the below error
 cluster_name = (response['metadata']['items'][1]('value'))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @kunal the code of my answer works. So if it doesn't with your response, then it means that you didn't show us the real response content

Comment: actually the key": "cluster-name" will not always be at index 1 and can be at different position. I want to get the value of "key": value wherever I have key: cluster-name

Comment: @kunal oh ok, see my edit

Comment: I am seeing the below error with your edited code

KeyError: 'items'

Comment: @kunal please make some effort, try to understand my code, the logic regalativly to the example dict I show, then compare to yours and try to fix it. If you want to develop learn a bit, you can't only wait for other to build your exact need (also if don't you give the good example)

Comment: I understand your code. I am just trying to see how to handle the situation where the key "items" is not present. the code does work where the key is present. However where key is not present I am facing the below error

for item in response["metadata"]["items"]:
KeyError: 'items'

Comment: I really appreciate all your help with this. I did try with the code you edited now earlier as well. However, my issue is with this code it just prints the output where the key items is present. My requirement is to print "cluster-name" as None where this key is not present

Comment: @kunal and you can't do that alone too ?

Comment: I tried the below code, but still dont see the output where they key isnt present as None

for item in response['metadata'].get('items', []):
  if item["key"] == "cluster-name":
    cluster_name = item.get('value', None)

Comment: @kunal see my edit with break/else

Answer (score 0):

You can try below :

```
response['metadata']['items'][1]['value']
```